Can a witness in court volunteer unsolicited information?
Can a witness volunteer unsolicited information whilst giving testimony in court, or are they limited to strictly answering the questions put to them?
When a witness is called to the stand they're normally asked to take an oath along the lines of 'tell the truth, the whole truth and nothing but the truth'
If the witness is limited to answering questions then there may be circumstances where the witness feels he/she hasn't been able to tell 'the whole truth' simply because neither prosecution nor defence asked the appropriate question.
It may be conceivable that there are some questions that neither the prosecution nor defence want to ask because they feel the answer would just muddy the waters. If the witness feels that something is relevant, and feels morally obliged to stick to the letter of his oath and tell 'the whole truth' does he have the right to make such a statement?
